# Python Value error using Pandas and Anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, group-by, pandas

```
ValueError:The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have a dataframe with many columns one of which is user_id.

I try the following line of code to threshold users who have less than 10 entries in the dataframe:

```
myDF.groupby("user_id").filter(lambda x:len(x)>10)
```

The value of myDF.groupby should be a dictionary with keys as user_ids and corresponding values as lists of integers (representing restaurant codes).

But I receive the aforementioned valueError. I am unable to figure out why this is happening as this worked with previous versions of pandas (when I was working on Enthought Canopy). But recently I made the switch to anaconda by Continuum analytics and this problem seems to be occurring. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of pandas? This looks like a bug in v0.12 (the first version with ``filter``) that was fixed in v0.13. Update with ``conda update pandas``.

Comment: @DanAllan that's the answer :)

Comment: yup I thought that was the case. Just wanted to make sure before changing stuff. Will check and reply.

Comment: @DanAllan you should post your comment as the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of pandas? This looks like a bug in v0.12 (the first version with `filter`) that was fixed in v0.13. Update with `conda update pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that @DanAllan was right. It turned out to be 0.12 v of pandas that had the error. I have updated to 0.14 (beta version) and it seems to be working fine.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: To be clear (for future readers) v0.13 would have sufficed; you don't need the 0.14 development version to avoid this bug.